# Error with opening navigation subform to SPECIFIC record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to open a navigation subform to a specific record. Below is my code.

- `List_22` is displaying `tblMainDERS`.
- Reference Number is a string. Reference Number exists in `tblMainDERS` and `tblMCV`
- `frmMCV` is displaying `tblMCV`. (I tried using `tblMCV.[Reference Number] = RefNum`, but that does not work either)

Everything works EXCEPT for the `where` statement in the `BrowseTo` line. My form opens to `frmMCV` in the navigation pane of `frmERS`, but displays the first record in the table, instead of the one specified by the reference number.

```
Private Sub List22_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not IsNull(Me.List22.Column(0)) Then
        RefNum = Me.List22.Column(0)
        Application.Echo False
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmERS", , , ("tblMainDERS.[Reference Number]= '" & RefNum & "'")
        DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmMCV", "frmERS.NavigationSubform", ("tblMainDERS.[Reference Number] = '" & RefNum & "'")
        Application.Echo True
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the openargs work ok in the previous line?  also, you say `frmMCV is displaying tblMCV.` but your criteria is `tblMainDERS.[Reference Number] ` ?

Comment: The previous line works flawlessly. When I enter tblMCV.[Reference Number] = RefNum, a pop up appears asking for the parameter after a DblClk on the list box

Comment: Can you add some screen shots of these values, just a screen grab of the table column, to show some values, so people can try to replicate.  One thing, there are no autofilters/opening code etc on the form you are trying to open that could interfere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use fieldname and parameter in the WHERE argument.

Simply: `"[Reference Number]='" & RefNum & "'"`